# Parse Internal array in list(object) data type in terraform 0.12

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

how can I parse this data type in terraform 0.12

```
 variable "groups" {
    type = list(object({
        group_id = string
        permissions = list(string)
    }))
}
```

Example:

```
 groups = [
    {
        group_id = "gcp-org-admin"
        permissions = [ "roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin",
                        "roles/resourcemanager.folderViewer",
                        "roles/viewer",
                        "roles/iam.organizationRoleViewer",
                        "roles/orgpolicy.policyViewer"
                      ]  
    },
    {
        group_id = "gcp-security-ops"
        permissions = [ "roles/resourcemanager.folderViewer",
                        "roles/logging.viewer",
                        "roles/monitoring.editor",
                        "roles/iam.securityReviewer"
                      ]
    }]
```

for each of the groups, I would like to pair group_id and each permissions
that is like

```
  {
    group_id = "gcp-org-admin"
    permissions = "roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin"
  },
  {
    group_id = "gcp-org-admin"
    permissions = "roles/resourcemanager.folderViewer"
  },
  {
    group_id = "gcp-org-admin"
    permissions = "roles/viewer"
  }
```

Would like to create organization_iam_resource

for each of the permissions within each group_id, I have to create a resource.

Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example as it shows you a possible answer and some problems associated with nested lists: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11036